# Sort AWS Instances by Tag:Name in PowerShell after Get-EC2Instance Cmdlet

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, sorting, aws-powershell

I'm trying to sort the AWS Instances I pull with the Get-EC2Instance cmdlet but the issue I'm facing is that the property is a Tag and I'm not sure how to format it properly. I only know about assigning simple properties like "Sort-Object -Property Name".

I used the following to get the AWS Instances filtered by the Name tag.

```
$ids = Get-EC2Instance -Filter @( @{name='tag:Name'; values="*EXAMPLE*"}) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty instances | #insert sort here
```

Trying to pipeline sort in the last part. I tried properties like tag, tag:Name, tag:Key=Name but all failed. When I used Get-EC2Image, I had no issues with Sort Name but can't figure it out for Get-EC2Instance.

There is a AWS CLI version and answer at [Sort EC2 Instances by Tag Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817450/sort-ec2-instances-by-tag-name) but I wasn't able to apply it to PowerShell.

EDIT: Rewrote question and added more details since it got downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the output to Sort-Object cmdlet. I dont have access to a AWS instance to test this. But try variation of this command

```
$ids = Get-EC2Instance -Filter @( @{name='tag:Name'; values="*EXAMPLE*"}) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty instances | Sort-Object $_.Tag.Value
```

There are two ways. You can get the object using the `$_`
OR 
You can reference the property directly by using a method chain like:

```
(Get-EC2Instance).instances.tag.value
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish but the Sort-Object cmdlet without any defined properties did not work.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check. There are two ways. You can get the object using the $_   OR you can reference the property directly by using a method chain like: (Get-EC2Instance).instances.tag.value

Comment: Sorry, I tested both methods and it did not sort on my end. The first one did not sort and just output the same unsorted list while the second method (Get-EC2Instance).instances.tag.value had an error of "Sort-Object : The value of a parameter was null; one of the following types was expected: {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}. It underlined after pipeline "Sort-Object (get-ec2instance).instances.tag.value"

Comment: Do you just need tag name ?  If so, try like this (get-ec2instance).instances.tag.value | Sort-Object $_

Comment: No, I still want to keep all the properties from instances like instanceId and PrivateIpAddress etc. I did find something that is kind of pointing me in the right direction. I found examples of using select-object on subproperties which I think is what I'm trying to achieve but still haven't gotten the correct format for the expression. Trying something like Select-Object @{Name="Name";E={$_.tags.key | where {$_.tags.key -eq "Name"}} but it's not working. Any ideas?